# how to specify peewee TextField index key length

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, mysql-python, peewee

How can i set the key length for TextField with peewee python orm. I am on python3.7 and i get this error message:

```
peewee.InternalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'text' used in key specification without a key length")
```

I tried specifying it like this:

```
text = TextField(unique = True, key_length = 255, index = True)
```

However that does not seem to work since it returns this:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key_length'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the index explicitly:

```
class Note(Model):
    content = TextField()
    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            SQL('create index note_content on note (content(100))'),
        )
```

Please note that specifying indexes on text fields in mysql is probably a bad idea. If you know the length ahead-of-time, probably better off just using a CharField() in that case.

Comment: thanks and thanks for peewee :), maybe i could calculate the key length of the index afterwards based on all the data i have in there and then create the key length index afterwards